# Should I use "that" after "whatever"

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses

Which is correct or better:

> Anyways, I hope they do whatever **that** is for the benefit of them and the region.
>
> Anyways, I hope they do whatever is for the benefit of them and the region.

Comment: I guess they are OK but don't read well. In the first one, *that* doesn't point to anything (some other context is needed). The second example is OK. But if you really want to add something, how about "Anyways, I hope they do whatever *they can* for the benefit of *themselves* and the region.

Comment: Also you might consider *anyway* vs. *anyways*, or just leave it out as it is kind of an excuse word (it tends to minimize the previous context). It makes your statement above seem like you don't really believe it will happen.

Comment: **whatever** can act either as a nominal (*I will drink whatever they serve*) or as a determiner (*I will drink whatever wine they serve*).  In either case it heads the relative clause and therefore clause-introducing **that** is not used. However, demonstrative pronoun **that** can be used with it  *They're ordering a #12 from the menu, whatever **that** is.*